# how to apply data binding Recyclerview if adapter not part of Viewmodel?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

We all know that adapter is related to view and shouldn't; be part of Viewmodel in android MVVM, but If we put Adapter in view then we can;t achieve the Databinding with recyclerview as Adapter is part of View and we only have an option left is find the Recyclerview with findviewById() and call setAdapter() in View(Activity and Fragment)? This is like partial Databinding some of the view elements are directly bound through ViewModel and Recyclerview is being set via View. Any solution for that , I want to achieve full data-binding.

Comment: Where are you using dataBinding then? Not in the view?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "full data-binding"?

Comment: @JohanFerreira  I mean I wand to bind all view to viewmodel, but in case of recyclerview I need to set adapter from View,

Comment: It's (merely) pointless to bind a `RecyclerView`... bind it's items instead.

Comment: I agree wirh @MartinZeitler. I see no added benefit when binding to the RecyclerView.